# How to remotely manage 2012 R2 print server

Tags: windows-server-2012-r2, remote, print-server

We have a Windows 2012 R2 server, that is running print services and hosting printers.

I am using the management console snapp-in on another 2012 R2 machine to try and access the server remotely and manage the printers. When I add the remote server to the snap-in, it does not show me any of the installed printers or anything, and there are no errors:

[image: Remote server added to snap-in, but shows nothing]

The firewall is off on both machines, so don't think there is a communication issue. Managing the printers locally on the print server is fine:

[image: Local management is fine]

I did read there may be a policy setting that prevents remote access to the spooler, but I have checked all GPOs, and can't see this is enabled anywhere.

Can anyone offer any advice on what else to try here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I removed the snap in from the console, and re-added it with the print server listed during the add. This solved it.

I suspect the issue was related to trying to add the print server to the snap-in, after the snap-in had been loaded into MMC